# Check parent controller name in nested controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am building a Rails 3.2 app.
In this app I got two controllers sharing the same nested controller (transactions).

The paths looks like this:

```
http://localhost:3003/admin/purchases/6/transactions
```

and like this

```
http://localhost:3003/admin/subscriptions/6/transactions
```

In the transactions index action, how can I check if the parent is either purchases or subscriptions?

Comment: You have several options here, the two I can think now are: **1):** Test the `params[:controller]` to see which controller you're in. **2):** Test if `request.path` (available in Controller) contains subscriptions/purchases

Comment: @MrYoshiji, your number 1 is wrong: in both cases he'll be in the `TransactionsController`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have defined this as a nested resource in your routes file, you could check for `params[:purchase_id]` and `params[:subscription_id]`:

```
if params[:purchase_id]
  # parent is purchase
elsif params[:subscription_id]
  # parent is subscription
end
```